# ambiguous argument from git merge-base on azure deveops

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm trying to get a reference to a sha value by using the command:

```
git merge-base master azure-test
```

This works on my local machine, but does not work on a build using Azure DevOps. I get the following error:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'git merge-base master azure-test': unknown
>   revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths
>   from revisions, like this:

I did changed the command to "refs/heads/master" and "refs/heads/azure-test" and added " -- " in between to no avail.

I'm also in a 'detached HEAD' state.

What else should I try?

Comment: Has the azure-test branch been pushed from your machine?

Comment: Yes.  So once  azure-test  is pushed from my machine, Azure listens to that and runs my build process which invokes a bash script inside the azure-pipelines.yml file.  It is the script in the yaml file where it errors.

Comment: The error message suggests that some Git command has gotten the literal text string `git merge-base master azure-test` as a single "word", perhaps as an argument to `git rev-parse` or `git show`. In other words, instead of *running* `git merge-base` with two words, `master` and `azure-test`, and taking its output and feeding that commit hash to another Git command, whatever system you are using just give that other Git command the whole thing, un-evaluated.

Comment: A note about `--`: it belongs after commits and before filenames. So in this case, Git is asking you to say `git merge-base master azure-test --`, which would likely give you an error message about `azure-test` not being a branch or commit, rather than being ambiguous.

Comment: But to answer your actual question, maybe `azure-test` should be replaced by `origin/azure-test`, if the build in devops is working from a fresh clone, which would have created a local branch for `master` but none of the others branches, by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the branch `azure-test` only exists as remote tracking branch `origin/azure-test` in the fresh clone you probably create in your devops scripts.

When you clone a Git repo, Git will create `master` by default, setting its upstream to `origin/master`, but it won't do that for other branches until you check them out.

So I believe this is what you need, if my assumptions are correct:

```
git merge-base master origin/azure-test
```

or else, if you eventually need to checkout the `azure-test` branch anyway:

```
git checkout azure-test
git merge-base master azure-test
```